# Check if username exists with Custom Validator

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have this custom validator

```
 <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
  ErrorMessage="Username already exists!" ForeColor="Red" 
  onservervalidate="checkUsername" ControlToValidate="TextBoxUsername" 
  meta:resourcekey="CustomValidator1Resource1">
 </asp:CustomValidator>
```

and this code behind

```
public void checkUsername(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        string connString = "Data Source=icsd-db.aegean.gr\\icsdmssqlsrv;Initial Catalog=icsd12015;Integrated Security=True;";
        string cmdText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE username LIKE '%' + @username + '%'";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBoxUsername.Text);

                int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                if (count > 0)
                {
                    args.IsValid = false; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to work.. any ideas?

(i even tried on setting the command ..LIKE '%user%'.. where user is an existing username
but it keeps letting me add it and the error never pops out)

the code of the button

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string HashPassword; 
        HashPassword=sha256(TextBoxPassword.Text);
        string connectionString = "Data Source=icsd-db.aegean.gr\\icsdmssqlsrv;Initial Catalog=icsd12015;Integrated Security=True;";
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string queryString = "INSERT INTO [Users] (username,password,name,surname,birthdate) VALUES ('" + TextBoxUsername.Text + "','" + HashPassword + "','"+ TextBoxName.Text +"','"+ TextBoxSurname.Text +"','"+ DropDownYear.Text +"/"+ DropDownMonth.Text +"/"+ DropDownDay.Text +"');";


        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(queryString, conn);


        try
        {

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new Exception(ex.ToString(), ex);

        }
        conn.Close();

        Response.Redirect("EpitixiaNewAccount.aspx", true);


        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn't seem to work? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil It doesnt Validate

Comment: "It doesnt Validate"... <3 ... but do you get any specific exceptions? Have you debugged and found anything wrong that can point us in the right direction? For example, maybe your TextBoxUsername's Text is null. Anything besides it doesn't validate would be helpful.

Comment: Considering the code You posted in Your question, You implemented only server-side validation. This does not block code execution, but only sets `Page.IsValid` flag to `false` if the validation fails. If You want to validate using client-side validation, which would block the execution, You can implement validation function in JavaScript like described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX. It it's helpful, I can post it as an answer.

Comment: '%' + @username + '%' - remove the inner apostrophes

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil it shouldn't let me add the new user when the creation button is clicked with a username typed in the TextBoxUserName that already exists in the table Users ..but it dont.. it doesnt work.. i can create more users with the same username.Does this cover you?

Comment: Could you post the click event logic of your "Save/Register" button? Make sure that you have the following before attempting to add the user: `if (!Page.IsValid) { return; }`

Comment: @LukaszM  i have an other custom Validator similar to this..the only two differences is that the commandText is this "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AsterasSe_IliakoSistima WHERE  iliako_sistima_id = 2SistimaID AND asteras_ID = 2AsterasID " and that this one works.All the other is the same code as the other and it doesnt let me do a second insert with the same IDs popping the error msg ( 2 = @ )

Comment: Please verify if in the other validator `ClientValidationFunction` property is assigned or `Page.IsValid` property is checked for it in the code-behind handler. There can also be some issues with `ValidationGroup` set differently. You also use `meta:resourcekey`, which can assign additional properties from the resources file, so please let us know if any other properties are set for this validator. Now, when You posted also the button handler, it seems that checking `Page.IsValid` should solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the code You posted in Your question, it seems that You implemented only server-side validation.

Please take note that server-side validation does not block code execution, but it only sets `Page.IsValid` flag to `false` if the validation fails. So, the code that adds a user will always run. In order to consider the results of the validation, You should check `Page.IsValid` flag in the method handler that tries to add user and run the code only if it's set to `true`.

You may also want to validate using client-side validation, which would block the code execution by preventing a postback. To do this, You can implement validation function in Java Script and attach it to the custom validator using `ClientValidationFunction` property.

On MSDN, You can find description of `ClientValidationFunction` and and example how to use both client-side and server-side validation with a custom validator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your WHERE clause. Change to:

```
string cmdText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE username = @username";
```

That way, it's more explicit. The former query with `LIKE` will match any username that *contains* the given parameter value.

**UPDATE**
Also, @LukaszM in the comments above provided additional insight. Start by setting the `args.IsValid` property to true, then proceed to attempt to invalidate it:

```
public void checkUsername(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = true;

    string connString = "...";
    string cmdText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE username = @username";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBoxUsername.Text);

            int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            if (count > 0)
            {
                args.IsValid = false; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even better, I'd skip the initial `args.IsValid` I added and proceed to set it as follows:

```
public void checkUsername(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
     string connString = "...";
    string cmdText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE username = @username";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBoxUsername.Text);

            int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            args.IsValid = (0 == count); 
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that you will need to decide what to do if for any reason checking against the database fails.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i tried this query too..it doesnt work either :/

Comment: still it lets me add an existing username

Comment: I see that you already marked this question as answered. If a validator doesn't seem to prevent the page from executing an action, then it's a sure sign that you're not checking the value of `Page.IsValid`. This is a common error. I've been there myself. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
   var query = from p in _db.MixtapezUser
                        where p.email.ToLower() == login.ToLower() && p.password == password || p.username.ToLower() == login.ToLower() && p.password == password
                        select p;
            _user = query.Count;
```

Need user like for this case, unsafe and allow anyone to any case.